# How to set a JQuery DataTable initial filter (and keep that for subsequent searches)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery's DataTable, version 1.10, server-side queries. I'd like to initially set it to filter for only the child objects of a specific parent object. I'm using "campaignId" for this. I'm used to adding this to the URL pre-JQuery,  but it seems that I should have an invisible column and have it set to filter for "campaignId" equaling my campaignId value. However, I don't want the campaignId column used in the global filter. Below is my code. Note that I created a createTable() method that is used to hide all the really JQuery-specific stuff. I just pass in a more generic set of parameters.
How can I get this to work?

```
var tableConfig =
{
  id:     '#bank_accounts',
  ajax:   '<s:property value="findBankAccountsURL"/>',    
  order:  [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
  search: {"regex": true},
  searchCols: 
  [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    { "search": "${campaignId}"}
  ],
  columns:
  [
    {"data": "accountName"},
    {"data": "accountNumber"},
    {"data": "bankName"},
    {"data": "campaignId", "visible": false, "search": {"value": ${campaignId} }}
  ],
  rowClickEventHandler: openBankAccount
};
var table = createTable(tableConfig);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I found that the answer was actually to use ajax.data (https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data). I had to modify the DataTablesParamUtility and JQueryDataTableParamModel classes that I had found on the web, but it all works now.